# How to filter out properties from array of object without any duplicate key-value?

Tags: javascript

I have a fetch method which is giving the below responseJson

```
[ {id: 1, cust_email: "abcd@gmail.com"},
 {id: 2, cust_email: "abcd@gmail.com"},
 {id: 3, cust_email: "wxyz@gmail.com"}]
```

And i want to handle this response to get the below format

```
[ {cust_email: "abcd@gmail.com"},
 {cust_email: "wxyz@gmail.com"}]
```

Any tips or suggestions ? Thanks

Comment: You want to remove duplicates from an array, and remove properties from an object. If you search for these terms (individually) instead of unrelated ones like JSON you should find existing answers. Always try and break down problems into the smallest possible parts.

Comment: Share your code please.

Comment: You might want to re-search loadash library https://lodash.com/docs/   which provides lot more utility functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `Set()` and `map()`:

```js
var response = [ {id: 1, cust_email: "abcd@gmail.com"},
{id: 2, cust_email: "abcd@gmail.com"},
{id: 3, cust_email: "wxyz@gmail.com"}]
response = [...new Set(response.map(i => i.cust_email))].map(i => ({cust_email: i}));
console.log(response);
```

Comment: In case anybody is wondering: [context](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)